# What does InsideReduction min2Axis do?

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-11

I'm working on a shader using HLSL and C++.
Recently I strugled over some specification for the Hullshader I do not know and can't find a good explenation.

```
[domain("tri")]
[partitioning("fractional_even")] //fractional_odd
[InsideReduction("min2Axis")]
[outputtopology("triangle_cw")]
[outputcontrolpoints(3)]
[patchconstantfunc("TessellationPatchConstantFunction")]
```

What exactely is this InsideReduction("min2Axis")]?
I figured out that InsideReduction is to calculate the inside tessellation dependent on the outside tessellation. But what exactely is min2Axis?

Many thanks for your answers in advance.